# What does BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly exactly do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

the MSDN says it "Adds an assembly to the application's set of referenced assemblies.". but how? where effects happens exactly?is there any ienumerable/list of referenced assembly to access and add manually to them?

actually if we call this method after app start it throws

> "This method can only be called during the application's pre-start
>   initialization phase. Use PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute to
>   declare a method that will be invoked in that phase."

ok. now i don't want to use it. i want to know what does do exactly and then i simulate in my custom function.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a good thing [we have the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Compilation/BuildManager.cs,ab8756fabdd9dd93):

```
public static void AddReferencedAssembly(Assembly assembly) 
{
    if (assembly == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
    }

    ThrowIfPreAppStartNotRunning();

    s_dynamicallyAddedReferencedAssembly.Add(assembly);
}
```

`s_dynamicallyAddedReferencedAssembly.Add` is a `List<Assembly>` of dynamically added assemblies which will be taken into account during compilation.

There is another internal method called `GetReferencedAssembiles` which gets all the assemblies for the project, which iterates and adds all the dynamically added assemblies to the list of referenced assemblies:

```
internal static ICollection GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig,
                                                    int removeIndex) 
{
    // shorted for brevity

    foreach (Assembly assembly in s_dynamicallyAddedReferencedAssembly)
    {
        referencedAssemblies.Add(assembly);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , but how we can access to the s_dynamicallyAddedReferencedAssembly ?

Comment: You don't, it's private. You add to it via `AddReferencedAssembly`.

Comment: but i can't do it after PreAppStart ,because of     ThrowIfPreAppStartNotRunning(); !

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://blog.thekfactor.info/posts/performing-activities-before-an-application-starts-using-the-preapplicationstartmethod-attribute/) will help with the `PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute.

Comment: The link above is broken @YuvalItzchakov .. thoughts?

Comment: @jcolebrand Sorry, I don't recall what was in that link.

Comment: hmmm... `blog.thekfactor.info’s server IP address could not be found.` ... could be my corporate VPN?

Comment: @jcolebrand I can't reach it either, it seems down.